# MouseOver and MouseOut In CSS

Tags: css, html

For using mouse into one element we use the `:hover` CSS attribute.  How about for mouse out of the element?

I added a transition effect on the element to change the color. The hover effect works fine, but what CSS attribute should I use for mouse out to apply the effect? I'm looking for a CSS solution, not a JavaScript or JQuery solution.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here is the best solution, i think.

**CSS onomouseout:**

```
div:not( :hover ){ ... }
```

**CSS onmouseover:**

```
div:hover{ ... }
```

It's better, because if you need to set some styles ONLY onmouseout and trying to do this in this way

```
div { ... }
```

you will set your styles and for onmouseover too.

Comment: Did not work for me, what I wanted was to display a different color when mouse is dragging a slider and mouse is in the slider(slider updates - green) or mouse is outside the slider and dragging(on mouse up slider does not update - red).

Comment: I wanted to apply an animation only when a mouseout event happened, but not at page load. This solution is not appropiate for that kind of requirement.

Comment: It not working like JavaScript you can see in this question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/73176586/18421540

Answer (score 23):

CSS itself does not support a `mousein` or `mouseout` selector.

The `:hover` selector will apply to the element while the mouse is over it, adding the style when the mouse enters and removing the style when the mouse leaves.

The nearest approach is to define the styles which you would place in `mouseout` within your default (non-hover) styles.  When you mouse-over the element the styles within `hover` will take effect, emulating a `mousein`, and when you move your mouse off the element the default styles will take effect again, emulating `mouseout`.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FMghK/), taken from [here](http://www.waynemoir.com/notebook/css/different-css-transitions-on-mouse-in-and-mouse-out/):

```
div {
    background: #2e9ec7;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 100px 0; 
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-border-radius 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: -moz-border-radius 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: border-radius 0.5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: border-radius 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: border-radius 0.5s ease-in;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}


div:hover {
    background: #2fa832;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(720deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(720deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(720deg);
    transform: rotate(720deg);
}
```

The `transition`s defined for the `div:hover` style will take effect when the mouse enters (and `hover` is applied).  The `transition`s for the `div` style will take effect when the mouse leaves (and `hover` is removed).  This results in the `mousein` and `mouseout` transitions being different.

Comment: transition: all 1s ease; fixed the issue. smooth transition when mouse out. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 7):

I think that I've found the solution.

```
.class :hover {
    /*add your animation of mouse enter*/
}

.class {
    /*
    no need for not(hover) or something else. 
    Just write your animation here and it will work when mouse out
    */
}
```

Just try it... :)

Answer (score 2):

You only need the `:hover` , when you mouse out of the element, it'll return to it's default non-:hover state, like this:

```
.class { color: black; } 
.class:hover { color: red; }
```

when you hover, the color will be red and when you "mouseout", the color will return to black because it no longer matches the `:hover` selector. This is the default behavior for all browsers, nothing special you need to do here.

Comment: Ops , I Googled before asking here. after Posting Question Continue My googling and find Answer, just i wanted to share Solution To Others , No More.