# How to not apply CSS :hover to parent elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want `:hover` not to be applied to parent elements, and when `:hover` is applied to the child, it also applies to parent divs.

```css
div{
  min-width:50px;
  min-height:50px;
  padding:12px;
  background:#0002;
}

div:hover{
  background:#f204;
  border:2px dashed #f20;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div> It work correct
    <div> how to hover this and parents don't not change back color
        <div> how to hover this and parents don't not change back color </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

if you open inspector from your browser like chrome you can select element by a button from top left corner or use shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+C i want to make something like this

Comment: When you hover a child, you are hovering the parent, that's a fact that you cannot avoid.

Comment: This is effectively the same question you've already asked (https://stackoverflow.com/q/73175944/82548); about nesting elements and hovering a descendant without hovering the parent. Please: understand that hovering a descendant explicitly - and by design - hovers the parent also.

Comment: There is no way to solve the problem??

Comment: The solution is to find an alternative means of creating your design that doesn't use nesting, or to let go of the belief that a child should be independent of their ancestors.

Comment: If you have to stick with that sort of HTML layout you'll need Javascript to do what you want. Is that acceptable?

Comment: That right JavaScript perfectly work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Fake Hover

only JavaScript work and css never can do this!

```js
const query = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for(let i = 0;i < query.length;i++){
  query[i].addEventListener('mouseover',over);
  query[i].addEventListener('mouseout',out);
}
function over(event){
  const element = event.target;
  element.setAttribute('hover','')
}
function out(event){
  const element = event.target;
  element.removeAttribute('hover');
}
```

```css
div{
  min-width:50px;
  min-height:50px;
  padding:12px;
  background:#0002;
}

div[hover]{
  background:#2f24;
  border:2px dashed #2a2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div> It work correct
    <div>  hover this and parents don't not change back color
        <div> hover this and parents don't not change back color </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a more specific selector and cannot simply use `div:hover`. Try something like this:

```css
div {
  min-width:50px;
  min-height:50px;
  padding:12px;
  background:#0002;
}

div > div > div:hover{
  background:#f204;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div> It work correct
    <div> how to hover this and parents don't not change back color
        <div> how to hover this and parents don't not change back color </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This `>` is called child combinator: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators

Comment: I want parents to have this possibility as well

Comment: I don't understand your requirement but maybe `div > div:hover, div > div > div:hover {}` is what you need

Comment: if you open inspector from your browser like chrome you can select element by a button from top left corner or use shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+C i want to make something like this

Comment: I am afraid you need JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class as below

CSS File

```
div{
  min-width:50px;
  min-height:50px;
  padding:12px;
  background:#0002;
}

el3:hover{
  background:#f204;
}
```

HTML File

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="el1"> It work correct
        <div class="el2"> how to hover this and parents don't not change back color
            <div class="el3"> how to hover this and parents don't not change back color </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I explained in other answers that we came to the conclusion that JavaScript is the only solution for us. The page is not static and the number of elements changes. Even if a class is defined for each element. Again, when the mouse is on the child, it also affects the parent.